# Python 3 Login Program Using Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, authentication, passwords

I am trying to create a login program for a project and I can't seem to figure out two things. The first is how to have the login info stored in the dictionary after i quit the program and the second is to figure out how to quit the program correctly. Thanks! Here is the source code.

```
#Dictionary
users = {}
#Used to quit/create/login users
status = ""
#Start Menu:Ask if user exists or create new user
def Display_Menu():
    status =input("Are you a registered user? (Yes/No)? Press q to quit: ")
    if status == "Yes":
        Old_User()
    elif status == "No":
        New_User()
#Creates New User
def New_User():
    Create_Login =input("Create login name: ")
    if Create_Login in users:
        print ("Login name already exist!")
    else:
        Create_Password =input("Create password: ")
        users[Create_Login] = Create_Password
        print("New User created!")     
#Login if old user
def Old_User():
    login =input("Enter login name: ")
    Password =input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == Password:
        print("Login successful!")
    else:
        print("User doesn't exist or wrong password!")
#Quits Program
if status == "q":
    exit()
while status !="q":
    Display_Menu()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, python program won't store the data in the memory, so I would say, you should create a **login_data.txt**.

The code could look something like this

```
import json # may not be required as per storing method

#Dictionary
with open("login_data.txt", "r") as login_file:
    try:
        users = json.load(login_file)
    except:
        users = {}
#Used to quit/create/login users
status = ""
#Start Menu:Ask if user exists or create new user
def Display_Menu():
    status =input("Are you a registered user? (Yes/No)? Press q to quit: ")
    if status == "Yes":
        Old_User()
    elif status == "No":
        New_User()
#Creates New User
def New_User():
    Create_Login =input("Create login name: ")
    if Create_Login in users:
        print ("Login name already exist!")
    else:
        Create_Password =input("Create password: ")
        users[Create_Login] = Create_Password
        print("New User created!")     
#Login if old user
def Old_User():
    login =input("Enter login name: ")
    Password =input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == Password:
        print("Login successful!")
    else:
        print("User doesn't exist or wrong password!")
#Quits Program (modified)
while True:
    if status in {"q", "Q"}:
        # store the data before quitting
        with open("login_data.txt", "w") as login_file:
            json.dump(users, login_file)
        break
    else:
        Display_Menu()
```

As for the *quitting* is concerned, the python program automatically quits after executing all the code. So, after the `break` statement is encountered, the program falls out of the `while` loop & since there is no more code after that, the program automatically exits.

Comment: The point here for OP is that you don't have to tell the program to quit. It just automatically quits once the code has finished executing and there are no more expressions to evaluate. It might be a bit tricky to see that it happens after the `break.`

Comment: Oh, forgot to comment that one. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I think your solution is fine, but it could be hard to see how it answers the original question.

Comment: I know the database storing is not very good, but for beginners, that could be helpful to get to know file-io.

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate the quick and concise responses. I was thinking of using a .txt file but didn't really know how to implement it.

Comment: You are welcome. I would recommend reading http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files for file input output. It works for every type of file, not just .txt

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

#Dictionary
with open("login_data.txt", "r") as login_file:
    try:
        users = json.load(login_file)
    except:
        users = {}
#Used to quit/create/login users

#Start Menu:Ask if user exists or create new user
def Display_Menu():
    status =input("Are you a registered user? (Yes/No)? Press q to quit: ")
    if status == "Yes":
        Old_User()
    elif status == "No":
        New_User()
    return status
#Creates New User
def New_User():
    Create_Login =input("Create login name: ")
    if Create_Login in users:
        print ("Login name already exist!")
    else:
        Create_Password =input("Create password: ")
        users[Create_Login] = Create_Password
        print("New User created!")
#Login if old user
def Old_User():
    login =input("Enter login name: ")
    Password =input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == Password:
        print("Login successful!")
    else:
        print("User doesn't exist or wrong password!")
#Quits Program (modified)
while True:
    if Display_Menu() in {"q", "Q"}:
        # store the data before quitting
        with open("login_data.txt", "w") as login_file:
            json.dump(users, login_file)
        break
```